# How to stroke a CGPath?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

To stroke a CG path, which should I use?

```
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
```

or

```
    CGContextDrawPath(context, .Stroke)
```

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stroking a path draws the outline of the path using the current settings. Always a stroke, never a fill.

`CGContextDrawPath` draws the path using the specified mode. If you pass in a mode of `kCGPathStroke`, it does the same thing as `CGContextStrokePath`

Likewise, if you call `CGContextDrawPath` with a mode of `kCGPathFill`, it does the same thing as `CGContextFillPath`

If you only want to stroke, not fill a path, then use `CGContextStrokePath`.